# Excel: How can I have something similar to Row() in a function

Tags: excel, vba

`=Row()` gives me the row the formula is calculated in.

I want to create a function, to be used in formulas, that will achieve the same (essentially, I want to replace a long formula with a simple function call).

How can I do that?

Specifically, I want it to work when I copy the cell, or use ctrl+d (so using ActiveCell in the function doesn't work for me)

Comment: Can you specify your question a bit further?! Do you want to create a User Defined Function, i.e. a VBA function that can be called from a cell - and in that function get use the row number? In this case, `Function myRow(rng as Range) as Variant: myRow = rng.Row: End Function` should give you a start.

Comment: Just tested `ActiveCell` and, in Excel 2003, both copy & paste and [Ctrl + D] works. But dragging the down right handler doesn't. And it won't re-calculate "`ActiveCell` address" even after save-close-open. Right now the only guaranteed way I can think of would be to pass `ROW()` as function parameter...

Comment: `I want to replace a long formula with a simple function call).` What is that formula?

Comment: @Peter: yes, i want a UDF. your myRow example requires that I pass in a range (e.g., =myRow(C3)), which i want to avoid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Application.Caller` to get information about where a function is called from.

example. Put this code in a module:

```
Function qq()
qq = Application.Caller.Row
End Function
```

and then you can use the function `=qq()` to return the row of the calling cell